# What's saved into cache file?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

What is saved into AUC file (cache file) of Axapta / Dynamics Ax 2009?

Does it save only objects, or maybe also column layout of the users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [AUC file](http://www.axaptapedia.com/index.php/Object_caching) stores object data, but no user defined data.

Basically it copies used objects from the servers AOD file to the clients AUC file.

Comment: And in my experience it will cache more elements if you are using the client through a user that has developer access.

Answer (score 0):

Column layouts are MorphX settings, which are stored in the syslastvalue table.  I think it is application specific stuff, like window position, file location, etc.of a specific user.  Delete the files, then open AX and you will see a screen flash briefly.  Try and screen cap that and I think you will have your answer.